# Unable to run sparkPi on Apache Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, bigdata

The following is my spark master UI which shows 1 registered worker .
I am trying to run the sparkPi application on the cluster ,using the following submit script

```
 ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://159.8.201.251:7077 \
   /opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/lib/spark-examples-1.2.1-hadoop2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar \
  1
```

but it keeps giving the following warning ,and never finishes executing :

```
 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

I start the master using `./sbin/start-master.sh`
I connect the worker using `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://x.x.x.x:7077`

[image: Spark master Web UI]
Logs on Master (keep repeating)

```
15/05/01 01:16:48 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150501005353-0000/40 on worker-20150501004757-spark-worker30-04-2015-23-11-51-1.abc.com-48624 (spark-worker30-04-2015-23-11-51-1.abc.com:48624) with 1 cores
15/05/01 01:16:48 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150501005353-0000/40 on hostPort spark-worker30-04-2015-23-11-51-1.abc.com:48624 with 1 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
15/05/01 01:16:48 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150501005353-0000/40 is now RUNNING
15/05/01 01:16:48 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150501005353-0000/40 is now LOADING
15/05/01 01:16:55 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
15/05/01 01:17:10 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
15/05/01 01:17:23 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150501005353-0000/40 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/05/01 01:17:23 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150501005353-0000/40 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/05/01 01:17:23 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 40
```

Logs on worker (keep repeating)

```
15/05/01 01:13:56 INFO Worker: Executor app-20150501005353-0000/34 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
15/05/01 01:13:56 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20150501005353-0000/35 for Spark Pi
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
15/05/01 01:13:58 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "java" "-cp" "::/opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/conf:/opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar:/opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/Spark/spark-1.2.1-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" "-Dspark.driver.port=48714" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@spark-master-node30-04-2015-23-01-40.abc.com:48714/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "35" "spark-worker30-04-2015-23-11-51-1.abc.com" "1" "app-20150501005353-0000" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@spark-worker30-04-2015-23-11-51-1.abc.com:48624/user/Worker"
15/05/01 01:14:31 INFO Worker: Executor app-20150501005353-0000/35 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
15/05/01 01:14:31 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20150501005353-0000/36 for Spark Pi
```

Comment: How are you initializing spark cluster? please add command.

Comment: have edited the question to include the commands

Comment: are you trying to run it on your PC??

Comment: No they are both VMs with 1 core ,1GB ram ,RHEL isnt that sufficient for the sparkPi application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of this error was : The workers could not really connect to the Master node as the ***spark master's IP and hostname was not present in the /etc/hosts file of the workers***. For the cluster to work it is essential that each node has the host entries of every other node in the cluster in its /etc/hosts file.
eg:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
10.0.2.12 master.example.com master
10.0.2.13 worker1.example.com worker1
10.0.2.13 worker2.example.com worker2
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of hosts file, pls?